# PowerShell command to forcefully perform Remove-Item or Move-Item command

Tags: powershell

Tried below command to remove a folder and to move one folder to another

```
$string2 = "20*.$e.*"
$path = "C:\Users\Desktop\Powershell_script\$string2"
Remove-Item $path -Recurse -Exclude "api"

Move-Item C:\Users\Desktop\Powershell_script\$string2 C:\Users\Desktop\Powershell_script2\
```

Above both command works fine but the when any file is open then the command shows access error or program is being used by another task like that.
Can the same command be altered to forcefully perform the function irrespective of file usage or open?

Comment: No. Good thing, too, because people might lose data otherwise. If you need to write to a file that another application has locked you need to close that application's handle to the file first. There are ways to do this (e.g. via the [`handle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) utility), but AFAIK nothing built into PowerShell.

Comment: Have you considered the `-Force` switch?

Comment: -Force works for Remove-Item but for Move-Item its not working

Comment: As an alternative to move the item, you could try to copy the item, and afterwards forcefully remove it.

Comment: The `-Force` switch is for hidden or read-only files. I would be surprised if it would cause the removal of locked files.

Comment: You want to [Force close files that are in use when the script runs](//stackoverflow.com/q/24180361)

Comment: yes...wanted to delete the folder irrespective of any usuage....even remove-item -recurse -force sometimes shows access denied